# NEON output generated by the simulator regarding (pipeline information, stalls, execution cycles) not clear

Tags: embedded, arm, simd, neon, cortex-a8

I have some problem understanding the output of NEON simulator. The output generated is cryptic and there is no proper documentation for understanding the simulator output.

for example : 
[image]

In the above figure the 1st column's information is not clearly explained.
What does lc mean?  Sometimes the syntax given below doesn't match the data format in the table.

The code and data are at http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/sample-55d49530 . I find some help at [Some doubts in optimizing the neon code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533833/some-doubts-in-optimizing-the-neon-code) but it is not completely clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some doubts in optimizing the neon code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533833/some-doubts-in-optimizing-the-neon-code)

Comment: I think you also don't use `@` feature properly.

Comment: It would also be useful for the community to know where the screenshot came from - clearly a simulator or profiler, but which one?

Comment: pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php is the webpage that can be used for profiling NEON code

Answer (score 1):

It is not 'LC' it is '1C', i.e. one-C, meaning that instruction takes one cycle.